# Name for "sharper than unital" algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

I call a (usually associative and commutative) linear algebra $A$ over a vector space $V$ with multiplication $\otimes$ and vector space sum $\oplus$ (for fairly obvious reasons) "Schur" if it is unital with unit element $e$, and for all $x\in A$
$$x\otimes x=e\oplus\cdots$$

(in contrast to $2e$ or $0e$ or whatever - sidenotes: "$\cdots$" may signify the empty set, and for complex objects one has $x\otimes x^*$ which gives one $E$), and likewise for all distinct ${x,y\in A}$,
$$ x\otimes y=0e\oplus\cdots$$

Surely a name for this was already given? There are so many epithets for algebras I didn't find the right one.

*Prominent example for $A$*: Irreducible representations of a group character table. I would also be interested in a small example ---associative and commutative--- which doesn't fall under this class.

Comment: Your example makes me think you are actually looking at a specifically chosen basis for which you want some property to hold. Also note that for irreps of a group you do not have usually $\langle \chi \otimes \chi, 1 \rangle = 1$ but $\langle \chi \otimes \chi^*, 1 \rangle = 1 $ where $\chi^*$ is the conjugate of $\chi$ (associated to the dual representation).

Comment: Notice that the example of irreducible representations has more structure: isomorphism classes of irreps over $\mathbb C$ admits a "trace" $\lambda$ sending $V$ to the multiplicity of $1$ in $V$ such that $\lambda(ab) = \lambda(ba)$, a commutative product $-\cdot -$ coming from $\otimes$ and an involution $(-)^*$ (coming from the usual duality $V\longmapsto V^*$) such that $\lambda(a^*\cdot b) = \langle a,b\rangle$. The irreps are orthonormal for this inner product and this is the condition that you want. So it seems that you want something like an orthogonal basis in a Frobenius algebra...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense as written. What is the $\cdots$ supposed to mean? Why can't I just take $\cdots = x \otimes x - e$?

Comment: @Pedro: Good hint, I look it up. Indeed, the whole question is obviously dependent on the chosen basis (but then, "unital" is too, or?)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan What the OP means is that $e$ appears with coefficient one in the expansion of $x\otimes x$ in a basis they like, it seems, etc. I tried to clarify this with my comment.

Comment: I think the OP is thinking about something weaker than a basis per se, but still stonger than they write, namely a pre-existing decompositon (as vectorspaces) of the algebra in two parts: $A = Ke \oplus Im(A)$ where $K$ is the ground field, and $Im(A)$ is a pre-specified co-dimension 1 subspace. This is a common situation when you have a star structure or trace (like mentioned above in the comments). E.g. in the quaternions you would have $Im(\mathbb{H}) = \textrm{span}(i, j, k)$ but the precise choice of basis elements of $Im(\mathbb{H})$ is pretty immaterial as long as they span that space

Comment: Then the condition in the question could be a condition on elements of $Im(A)$, but not on all of $A$ since obviously you would have $2e \otimes 2e = 4e$ and not $2e \otimes 2e = e$ as the condition implies